# OR , AND conditions in INDEX AND SMALL

Tags: excel

I have this formula which works perfectly

```
   =IFERROR(INDEX(Lista!$A$2:$A$250;SMALL(IF(Lista!$D$2:$D$250="A";ROW(Lista!$D$2:$D$250)-ROW(Lista!$D$1));ROW(1:1)));"")
```

But when i want to add other AND and OR conditions i get just one wrong row , not the exact value .

this what i tried :

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX(Lista!$A$2:$A$250;SMALL(IF(OR(AND(Lista!$K$2:$K$250="x";Lista!$D$2:$D$250="A");AND(Lista!$K$2:$K$250="x";Lista!$D$2:$D$250="B"));ROW(Lista!$D$2:$D$250)-ROW(Lista!$D$1));ROW(1:1)));"")
```

I have done `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER`   .

Why this didnt work ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array formulas do not like `AND` and `OR`.  Replace them with the Mathematical operands `*` and `+` respectively:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Lista!$A$2:$A$250;SMALL(IF((((Lista!$K$2:$K$250="x")*(Lista!$D$2:$D$250="A"))+((Lista!$K$2:$K$250="x")*(Lista!$D$2:$D$250="B")));ROW(Lista!$D$2:$D$250)-ROW(Lista!$D$1));ROW(1:1)));"")
```

This is still and array formula so use Ctrl-Shift-Enter to verify when exiting edit mode.

The idea is that any result that return `>0` is read as true.  And the fact that `True/False` is a Boolean that can can return `1/0` respectively when used in mathematical equations, using the operands should return the correct true.

Comment: You was right man :) . it worked perfect . This must be a bug in excel , How they miss AND OR  to not work with ? But anyway thanks so much :)

Comment: it is just that AND and OR check for all values. and if you have an array it will check each part and return just one expression... it is not like they missed something, they work like they should ;)